# How to encrypt PayPal's button

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-buttons

I'm little bit fighting with the PayPal button. I have the unencrypted version which works great, the problem is that the customer can change the amount etc. I found out that is possible to encrypt the data. I used these [two](http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php) [examples](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/ppdts.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=502&p_created=1179163082&p_sid=1Ya-Caak&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_lva=&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9MzIsMzImcF9wcm9kcz0wJnBfY2F0cz0mcF9wdj0mcF9jdj0mcF9wYWdlPTEmcF9zZWFyY2hfdGV4dD1lbmNyeXB0ZWQgd2Vic2l0ZSBwYXltZW50cw**&p_li=&p_topview=1). The problem is that I'm getting 'We were unable to decrypt the certificate id.'. Maybe it looks like I don't have right PayPal public certificate? I downloaded it from the backend, the only one I found. There wasn't any reference where to download it in non of the turorials. I'm trying this on sandbox right now. Please can anyone advice?

Comment: I think that you already answered your question.

Comment: @Māris The problem is that I didn't found any other certificate. So if you know where to find it can be helpful. This one was from Profile / Hosted payment settings / Website payment certificates

Comment: can't you just verify the amount in your backend? Consider quantities lower that the actual price as a donation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, it may help you: [Dynamic Paypal button encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106376/dynamic-paypal-button-encryption); also verify you're using the current certificate and be advised that if you're doing tests in the sandbox, the sandbox uses a different certificate of the one you get in the main site (and also you must have an account in the sandbox which is different of your main account).