# How to validate PayPal return data?

Tags: php, validation, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I'm integrating paypal and I have done it correctly. I have set the return URL, so it give me below result set in url `$_GET`.

```
Array ( [tx] => 7XV08083GT683520Y [st] => Completed [amt] => 22.16 [cc] => USD [cm] => [item_number] => item_number )
```

My concern is there is no way to validate the data that has returned from Paypal. I have experienced with other payment gateways. Other payment gateways allow you to do `hashMatch` which allows to make sure that submitted data by the form has been not edited.

My form is as below.

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" value="dasun_1358759028_biz@archmage.lk" name="business">
<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">
<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" value="AM Test Item" name="item_name">
<input type="hidden" value="22.16" name="amount">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" value="item_number" name="item_number">
<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>
```

My php code output

```
 <input type="hidden" value="50.16" name="amount">
```

But I used firebug and edited it to below & did the payment.

```
<input type="hidden" value="22.16" name="amount">
```

Still I get the result as it's a `Completed` payment but It should not be since I have made changes manually. Anyone who has a knowledge can edit them. How can I make sure that this is a valid payment ? How can I make sure that form data is not edited like I did ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is critical and requires DB interaction should use Paypals IPN for data that MUST be verified. Essentially Paypal will Post the URL on your website with data and your script will have to post the exact data back plus a command to verify that the data is indeed correct. After Paypal gives an "verified" response, then you update your data.

Another alternative is using Paypal's express checkout, essentially you are getting an "ok" to charge a customer for "x" amount, once the customer agrees to pay the amount, you post the data to Paypal with the customers "agreement" and you will get a response if the transaction was complete or not.

https://www.paypal.com/ipn

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

Before redirecing to paypal store your data in database (product_id, amount, quantity, etc)

After returning from payapl check the return values with your database.

This is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: thank you very much. what I want to know is whether there is a another way like other payment gateways. something like hashMatch

Comment: I think you can send some custom values to paypal, and paypal will return these values also, so you can make a comaprison between these values too, still you need to store these values some were in your page (session OR database).

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. Anyway Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to notify whether you are returned from paypal than You should use Paypal API instead of "Buy now" button API provide more flexibility and power to control your payment process

Answer (score 0):

You may try some of these:

1) Creating an Encrypted Button on the PayPal Website

2) Encrypting Buttons Dynamically With Encrypted Website Payments (EWP)

available at:  http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide/encryptedwebpayments.html

Also, this SO link has some details: 
[Dynamic PayPal button generation - isn't it very insecure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322247/dynamic-paypal-button-generation-isnt-it-very-unsecure)