# Security: Passing payment amount to PayPal

Tags: security, paypal

From what I understand, using the PayPal api, you can pass your payment amount by populating a hidden HTML input field which will be submitted to PayPal.

What I've got so far looks somewhat like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="60.00">
```

My question is - isn't this super unsafe? What's there to stop someone from changing the payment value in the element inspector for instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PayPal amount tampering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729023/paypal-amount-tampering)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use PayPal [**ButtonManager API**](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview/) operation in order to programatically create, manage, edit, and delete PayPal Payment Standard buttons, which are the same kind of buttons that you can create from the PayPal Profile.
Hosted buttons created by this API reside on PayPal and can use all features, including inventory management; however, you can use this API to create code for non-hosted Standard buttons as well.

The button you will create from this API request will look like:

> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=19218

As you can see no values like "business", "amount" or others are visible and for this reason this would be a safe solution and personally I'd recommend it.

Back to your question "*What's there to stop someone from changing the payment value in the element inspector for instance?*"

We recommend to use API requests (see [ExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) or **ButtonManager** to create Standard buttons) and **Instant Payment Notifications** service ([IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)), which is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use IPN messages to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other transaction-related information.

Comment: Is the ButtonManager button customisable? I'd like to remove the PayPal branding from it and keep my own website branding on the button.

Comment: Using BMCreateButton API Operation: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/ - you can customize your button. If you want to insert your logo instead of the standard PayPal button, you can do that by modifying the "src" value set up in the input type="image".

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you need a paid account to be able to use it fully or is it free?

Comment: That's completely free of charge. Another option you may want to look into which is a little more flexible, is PayPal Express Checkout. That's a full server-to-server API-based solution where you have more control over what, how and when you're sending data to us.