# Is it safe to redirect user to PayPal checkout page with all the form information in the link?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have this simple page where people can buy a rank for $24.99. However, they must enter their `username` and their `favNum`. These 2 user inputs get validated by the `is_favnum_valid()` and `is_username_valid()` functions. If any of the inputs are not valid, then the page is reloaded again with an error message showing. However, if the input is valid, then we redirect the customer to PayPal, where they pay via PayPal.

**My question** is, on line 47 (the `if ($errorMsg == "")` if statement block). I build the link to redirect the customer to. Is that safe? If its not safe, what should I do to redirect the customer so they can pay for the item. It is important for me somehow save the `username` and `favNum` into the database if the customer has paid for the item successfully.

**My Concern** is that it is exposing my listener URL `http://example.com/ipn.php`, its exposing all the settings I am using to make the order, people  can change the custom field and the fact people can just make up their own links/orders up and try and purchase items by just visiting this link:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=Premium rank&item_number=10&amount=24.99&currency_code=USD&business=test@gmail.com&no_shipping=1&custom=coolusername:5&no_note=0&return=http://example.com/success.php&cancel_return=http://example.com/cancel.phpl&notify_url=http://example.com/ipn.php
```

I also use the `custom` field in this PayPal request to store the `favNum` and `username`. So when my PayPal listener hears that the payment was successful, it will add the transaction details into my database, as well as the `username` and `favNum` PayPal sends you in the custom field when you are listening.

---

**shop.php**

```
<?php

$errorMsg = "";

// Checks if the username is valid.
// A valid username only contains letters
// @return boolean - true of username is valid otherwise false
function is_username_valid($username) {
    if (ctype_alpha($username)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Checks if the favNum is valid.
// A valid favNum must be an integer
// @return boolean - true of favNum is valid otherwise false
function is_favnum_valid($favNum) {
    if (ctype_digit($favNum)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // Check if username and favNum is set
    if (!isset($_POST["username"]) || !isset($_POST["favNum"])) {
        $errorMsg = "Please enter a username and your Favorite number<br>";
    } else {
        // Check if username is not valid
        if (!is_username_valid($_POST["username"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Username must be letters only<br>";
        }

        // Check if favNum is not valid
        if (!is_favnum_valid($_POST["favNum"])) {
            $errorMsg .= "Favorite number must be an integer<br>";
        }
    }

    // If there has been no errors with the user's input
    // redirect to paypal page so user can pay
    if ($errorMsg == "") {

        $query = array();
        $query['cmd'] = '_xclick';
        $query['item_name'] = 'Premium Rank';
        $query['item_number'] = 2;
        $query['amount'] = '24.99';
        $query['currency_code'] = 'USD';
        $query['business'] = 'test@gmail.com';
        $query['no_shipping'] = '1';
        $query['custom'] = $_POST["username"] . ":" . $_POST["favNum"];
        $query['no_note'] = 0;
        $query['return'] = 'http://example.com/return.php';
        $query['cancel_return'] = 'http://example.com/cancel.php';
        $query['notify_url'] = 'http://example.com/ipn.php';

        header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . http_build_query($query));
        exit(0);

    }



}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Buy premium rank for $24.95</p>

<?php

if ($errorMsg != "") {
    echo ('<p style="color: red;">Errors:<br>' . $errorMsg . '</p>');
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="shop.php">
  Enter Your Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Letters only">
  <br>
  Enter Your Favorite Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="favNum" placeholder="Integer only">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Buy">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One way is to display a form that contains a single button and a collection of hidden fields which contain the actual order information. This form uses the `post` method instead of `get`. See step 3 for an example - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-paypal-payment-form--net-6

Comment: @waterloomatt I don't think you understood the question? If I had them as hidden fields, people can still see my paypal IPN url and all my order settings

Comment: There shouldn't be anything sensitive in the form body. This is probably beyond the scope of your question, but the IPN *should* be publicly accessible since this is where PayPal sends back the status of the payment. If you're concerned amount tampering then you need to do validation when the IPN response is returned to you. Here's an example workflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19729378/296555. I have to scratch my head why PayPal didn't implement a hash check like other processors do.

Comment: To answer your question directly, post via a link or posting via a form with hidden fields is equally (in)secure. The latter will only slow down the most rudimentary attempts to post invalid payments. Some people implement an automatic redirect but again, this only stops the little old lady whose buying new sewing needles. You need to validate the response from PayPal when the IPN response comes back. The major caveat here is that the payment has already been processed by the time the response comes back so you'll need to handle that.

Comment: Final note - as an alternative to express checkout, you might want to look into `encrypted buttons` as a way to secure your checkout process. Here's a decent SO question/answer - https://stackoverflow.com/q/6322247/296555

Comment: @waterloomatt thank you for your answer. Do you have any good tutorials for the IPN listener. I think I need to make the listener really secure with lots of if statements checking the details of the paypal transaction. Then I won't have to care about the form

Comment: @waterloomatt Also I have a question. How did this person https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322247/dynamic-paypal-button-generation-isnt-it-very-insecure not put a `notify_url` field in their form. How will paypal know where to send the information of the transaction

Comment: @waterloomatt Also third question, where can I find more form fields like `$query['no_note'] = 0;` Is there a place where I can see what parameters I can set and what the parameters actually mean?

Comment: @waterloomatt I took a look at the encrypted button link you sent. Does this mean on every page load I generate a new encryption or can I just use the same encryption every time so I don't need to keep  calling paypal over and over again