# The best way to secure paypal payment?

Tags: php, encryption, paypal

What method would be the best to secure paypal payment ?
Through PKCS7 encryption as discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322247/dynamic-paypal-button-generation-isnt-it-very-insecure?answertab=active#tab-top)
or maybe through openSSL as discribed [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0P017Q).

Is PKCS7 not possible to decrypt ?