# Does PayPal support the Dirham?

Tags: php, paypal, currency, paypal-sandbox

I am setting up my PayPal, but the currency I need is not on the pull down list.

I live in Dubai and the currency is United Arab Emirates, Dirham (AED). Is there a add-on I need or an "other" option available? anyone know the way how to add AED to Paypal.

Comment: You should be asking Paypal support this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [their site](https://www.paypal.com/worldwide/)  they do not support your currency. Probably, you need to do your transactions in USD

Official quote:

> Send and receive payments in these countries. Withdraw from your
>   PayPal account to a U.S. bank account. In addition, withdraw to a
>   credit or debit card in countries marked with a (+).

Note: UAE is marked as +

Comment: can you help me were to get the pay pal encrypted button sample code in php.

Comment: please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106376/dynamic-paypal-button-encryption

Comment: Thanks bro .can i get you mail id if u wish