# PayPal does not support your store currency. Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this error on my woocommerce web site:
Gateway Disabled: PayPal does not support your store currency.
Anyone have a specific solution or any wp plugin for this?
How do I work around this? There must be a way...

I am using currency Saudi United Arab Emirates Dirham (د.إ).

Thanks

Comment: maybe this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660013/does-paypal-support-the-dirham