# Paypal Button creation/encryption

Tags: button, dynamic, encryption, paypal

I've search for this online but couldn't find anything conclusive, yet.

I wish to make a large (yet unknown) number of paypal buttons, different prices, currencies, etc.

I have been following the encryption methodology and I came to a stop/point of additional research when I discovered that each encrypted button must be created on the command line and copied to my website.

This doesn't seem feasible if I require a large number of buttons, and due to this (apparent) absurdity I feel that I must be missing something obvious? Some sites have 100s/1000s of different prices/buttons which must be dynamically created.

Or is the correct procedure to leave the buttons unencrypted, thus dynamically created, and then use the IPN Listener to validate payments?

I'd be happy if someone could just point me towards a few tutorials/webpages.

Thank-you kindly for the help

Joseph

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Paypal button encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106376/dynamic-paypal-button-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a start:
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside

I use custom created buttons all the time.