# Is it possible to create a dynamic paypal payment link?

Tags: php, paypal

I'll be serving this via PHP, so it'll be more difficult to hijack. It's a temporary solution that'll be manually reviewed, so I'm not particularly worried about security. But, I was wondering if it's possible to create a link that would work with variables? Something like this:

https://paypal.com/pay?type=link&price=55aud&item=coffee

After thoroughly searching PP's API documentation I can't find anything of the type.

Comment: such as any paypal 'buy now' button currently in existence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Paypal button encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106376/dynamic-paypal-button-encryption)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.  You just need to build your string dynamically with PHP.  For example, using your link sample, we might end up with something like this:

```
$price = 55;
$item = 'coffee';
$currency_code = 'aud';

$paypal_url = 'https://paypal.com/pay?type=link&price='.$price.'&currency_code='.$currency_code.'&item='.$item;
```

Of course, you could use static variables like I did here, or you could load the URL items with session variables, database data, etc.  Once the URL is prepared you can output it and attach it to a link, button, simply redirect straight to it, or whatever you need to do.